# Intellij Idea insert/overwrite behaviour

Tags: intellij-idea

I changed couple of things in Intellij Idea Settings and I don't know where I changed insert/overwrite behaviour each other. When I press Insert on keyboard I have Insert option in bottom bar selected and cursor is fat. When I press Insert again I have thin cursor and Overwrite option selected.
What I did wrong?

Comment: Just restart intellij? Sounds like a tangle...

Comment: I tried it with no luck:/

Comment: Normal when Insert is pressed cursor is fat and code is overwritten. I've exactly opposite behaviour...

Comment: Yep, again no luck...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Settings` > `IDE Settings` > `Editor` > `Appearance` > Disable `Use block caret`